# V2P Windows guest on Linux host; VirtualBox dynamic VDI

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, conversion

- Hardware: Laptop with 2x 500GB SSD + 1x 2TB HDD
- Host: Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon 64-bit
- Virtualization software: VirtualBox 5.1.22 r115126
- Guest: Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit; dynamically allocated and encrypted VDI

---

I originally thought it's impossible to de-virtualize a VM. But as it turns out, it is not out of reach. I googled many successful and also unsuccessful attempts.

So the question stands:

### How to do V2P (Virtual-to-Physical) conversion in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Decrypt the VM: Uncheck the following box in VM settings:

   > Enable encryption

   It will ask you for password after hitting OK.
2. Convert the dynamic VDI to usable format:

   ```
   VBoxManage internalcommands converttoraw /path-to-VDI /path-to-store-RAW
   ```
3. Log into terminal as root, e.g.:

   ```
   sudo -i
   ```
4. Overwrite the destination disk with the RAW file:

   ```
   pv < /path-to-store-RAW > /dev/sdX
   ```

---

Notes:

1. It is only my personal preference to use `pv`, you can use `dd` or even `cat` for the last step.
2. In my case this process worked 100%, I hope it helps anyone too.